# Автоматом удаляются все скачанные файлы через FTP на MacOS

Tags: java, macos, ftp

Собственно в этом и фигня.

Качаю файл(ы) при помощи https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/ с FTP сервера. Они успешно сохраняются на диске. Файлик даже можно открыть. Но когда я останавливаю программу, все что было скачано на компьютер автоматом удаляется. ВТФ?

Вот код который отвечает за скачивание:

```
try {

    ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

    try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destination)) {
        ftpClient.retrieveFile(path, os);
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    LOGGER.error("FTP CLIENT GET FILE CONTENT ERROR", e);
}
```

`ftpClient` класс из либы.

**UPDATE!**

1. Этот момент появляется на любой ОС.
2. Этот момент появляется только при запуске приложения в Debug режиме.

**SOLUTION**

Проблема решена. 
Бага (или фича) найдена. Она в методе deleteOnExit(); у класса File из jdk. Перед тем как скачать файл с фтп я удаляю файл локально, если он есть.
Изучив код метода я увидел что он добавляет файлы на удаление при завершении программы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена.

Бага (или фича) найдена. Она в методе `deleteOnExit();` у класса `File` из JDK. Перед тем как скачать файл с FTP сервера я удаляю файл локально, если он есть.

Изучив код метода я увидел что он добавляет файлы на удаление при завершении программы.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в ваше приложение закрытие коннекта

```
finally
        {
            if (ftpClient.isConnected())
            {
                try
                {
                    ftpClient.disconnect();
                }
                catch (IOException f)
                {
                    // do nothing
                }
            }
        }
```

Аналогично, как указано в примере приложенном вами же

Comment: Нет. не помогло. Скачал файл, остановил программу - все удалилось. Это не библиотека делает. Она только скачивает.

Comment: Так, а теперь можно поподробнее, пожалуйста? [Здесь](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/download_net.cgi) Можно скачать и библиотеку, и рабочее приложение. Под приложением, что вы понимаете, ваше собственное приложение или то, что Apache предоставляет? Что вы запускаете и как? Через среду разработки запустили и качаете или запускаете через командную строку, качаете что-то, потом закрываете приложение. И лучше, ответ на этот комментарий добавьте в ваш вопрос