# Удаляются файлы и фрагменты кода на wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, ftp, elementor

Редактирую тему "classima" на wordpress. Добавил новый блок, сохранил, миллион раз в процессе работы все сохранял. На следующий день смотрю, этого блока нет ни на странице, ни в коде. Вчера почти половину страницы изменил(точнее менял файл archive-list-4.php). Сегодня смотрю этого файла нет. Так вот вопрос. Я ведь все сохраняю и проверяю, чищу кэш, все нормально работает, но через какое то время, сайт живет своей жизнью. Может ли быть такое, что файлы и фрагменты кода, как то сами по себе удаляются.(работал через ftp). Или заказчик лазил на elementor-е, и сам что то удалил?

Comment: возможно еще ктото работает и перезалил свою версию темы в которой нет ваших правок

Comment: @Darth KYL Это вообще капец, стоит ли отказаться от заказа? Я уже неделю делаю, завтра сдавать, а тут такое

Comment: у вас сохранилась локальная версия ваших правок? так же если вы работаете через phpstorm и выкачивали тему до этого то есть шанс что все правки сохранились в local history. в любом случае лучше вести разработку локально чтобы не было таких ситуаций

Comment: @Darth KYL  неа, ничего локально не сохранял. Если вы про бэкап говорите. Делал все на sublime)

Comment: @Darth KYL https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/974854/Автоматом-удаляются-все-скачанные-файлы-через-ftp-на-macos?rq=1 этот вопрос, может ли быть, что у меня такая же проблема?

Comment: вы же не скачивали файлы, а закачивали их на сайт клиента который скорее всего работает, и лежит на обычном шаред хосте

Comment: @Darth KYL теперь буду работать локально. Ладно, спасибо

Comment: Ну что же, хороший урок, чтобы начать использовать копии всего и всегда. Как файлов, так и базы.

Comment: Работать надо на тестовом клоне, а не на продакшене! И никому не давать доступ к разрабатываемому сайту.